# Shared Preference doesn't save Drawable Resource Ids correctly if updated drawable folder

Tags: java, android

i have a Custom Object Card()`
public Card(String Element , String Color , int ResourceId , int CardNumber ,String Special){

```
    mResourceId = ResourceId ;
    mCardNumber = CardNumber ;
    mElement = Element ;
    mColor = Color ;
    mSpecial=Special;
}`
```

mResourceId is a drawable of the Card image
when i save an Arraylist of type Card to Shared Preference and then add a single image to the drawable folder and update the app , all Card ResourceIds of the Arraylist are mixed and do not show correctly[The normal images of the arraylist of Cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Xr0.png)

[incorrect images replace the cards after adding some new images to the drawable folder and updating the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ7gZ.png)

i am sure that the new images' names that i added to the drawable folder do not match any name of the existing ones

```
public class Card implements Parcelable{
private int mResourceId, mCardNumber;
private String mColor, mElement,mSpecial,mResId;

public Card(String Element , String Color , int ResourceId , int CardNumber ){

    mResourceId = ResourceId ;
    mCardNumber = CardNumber ;
    mElement = Element ;
    mColor = Color ;
}

public Card(String Element , String Color , String ResourceId , int CardNumber ){

    mResId = ResourceId ;
    mCardNumber = CardNumber ;
    mElement = Element ;
    mColor = Color ;
}


public Card(String Element , String Color , int ResourceId , int CardNumber ,String Special){

    mResourceId = ResourceId ;
    mCardNumber = CardNumber ;
    mElement = Element ;
    mColor = Color ;
    mSpecial=Special;
}


protected Card(Parcel in) {
    mResourceId = in.readInt();
    mCardNumber = in.readInt();
    mColor = in.readString();
    mResId = in.readString();
    mElement = in.readString();
    mSpecial = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<Card> CREATOR = new Creator<Card>() {
    @Override
    public Card createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Card(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Card[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Card[size];
    }
};


public Object getResourceId() {
    if (mResId==null){return mResourceId;}
    else {return mResId;}

}

public int getResourceId(Context context) {
    try {
        return context.getResources().getIdentifier(mResId, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}

public void setResourceId(int ResourceId) {this.mResourceId = ResourceId;}

public void setElement(String Element) {this.mElement = Element;}

public void setCardNumber(int CardNumber) {this.mCardNumber = CardNumber;}

public int getCardNumber() {
    return mCardNumber;
}

public String getCardElement() {
    return mElement;
}

public String getCardColor() {
    return mColor;
}

public String getSpecial() {
    return mSpecial;
}

public boolean isPowerCard(){
    boolean isspecial=false;
    if (mSpecial==null){isspecial= false;}
    else {isspecial= true;}
    return isspecial;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(mResourceId);
    dest.writeInt(mCardNumber);
    dest.writeString(mColor);
    dest.writeString(mElement);
    dest.writeString(mSpecial);
}
```

}

Comment: Be careful that `R.whatever` resources are mostly generated at runtime. I'm not sure what you are asking, but if you want to save values like images, you have to save them as blob, or use efficient storage solutions (like Firebase)

Comment: @ArthurAttout What is blob?

Comment: Stands for Binary Long Object. Basically, you store the entire picture itself, like a JPG or a PNG. If you save the `R.drawable` value, it's just an int that refers to a resource at runtime. But it's completely meaningless out of context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resource id's are generated dynamically as the app updates.So it is failing in your case.

You can try to store the name of the resource in shared preference and use the name to get the id of the resource.

```
    Resources resources = getResources();
    String resourceName = resources.getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.resource);
```

You can then retrieve the id from shared preference.

```
intresId = resources.getIdentifier(resourceName, "drawable", "your.package.name");
```

Comment: , i am sure that strings are saved correctly , but i need to update the declaration of about 500 Cards , so it will be time cost , also i will need to generate the id at method getResourceId() in my Card class , how can i refer to getResources in not Activity class?

Comment: You need  the activity context to call the method getResourceId(). Storing id's is not feasible and achievable as they are generated dynamically every time.You can refresh the id's in shared preference every time the app is updated.

Comment: thanks it worked , i just passed a paramter context , but i now need to change about 500 Cards i made